# Spring Boot application.properties appear unregistered when accessed from constructor

Tags: spring, spring-boot, application.properties

This is the code that I have:

```java
@Component
@Configuration
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class Program {
    @Value("${app.title}")
    private String appTitle;
    
    public Program() {
        System.out.println(appTitle);
    }
}
```

The application.properties has

```
app.title=The Program
```

The output is `null` insteaf of `The Program`.

So, what am I missing?  I have tried several examples; none worked.

Answer (score 3):

Since `appTitle` is an autowired field, it is not set until after the object is initially constructed.  This is why the value is still null in your example.  The bean construction process in this scenario is as follows:

1. The `Program` constructor is called, creating a new `Program` instance
2. The `appTitle` field is set on the newly constructed bean to `${app.title}`

The ideal fix for this depends on your goals.  If you truly need the value within the constructor, you can pass it in as an autowired constructor parameter.  The value will then be available within the constructor:

```java
@Component
@Configuration
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class Program {
    public Program(@Value("${app.title}") appTitle) {
        System.out.println(appTitle);
    }
}
```

If you don't need it in the constructor itself, but need it for the proper initialization of the bean, you could alternatively use the `@javax.annotation.PostConstruct` annotation to make use of it after the object's construction but before it is made available for use elsewhere:

```java
@Component
@Configuration
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class Program {
    @Value("${app.title}")
    private String appTitle;

    @PostConstruct
    public void printAppTitle() {
        System.out.println(appTitle);
    }
}
```

Finally, if you don't need the value at construction time, but need it during the life of the bean, what you have will work; it just won't be available within the body of the constructor itself:

```java
@Component
@Configuration
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class Program {
    @Value("${app.title}")
    private String appTitle;
}
```

Comment: First example does not help, I need to have a constructor declared as Program(). For second and third, it is not clear what you are trying to explain... I do need the application.properties in a constructor. But OK, someone else might not...

Comment: Can you explain why you need a no-argument constructor and access to the properties in the constructor?  It sounds like you might be running into the XY problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/308327), and a concrete example might allow someone to get you a solution to the actual issue you're trying to solve.

Comment: Sorry but I see no reason why not to use the no-argument constructor. It is a very common thing to do, and I am very puzzled about why it cannot be used with application.properties... It just doesn't make any sense, and looks like bad engineering on spring-boot part. Anyway, moving on... there are other frameworks that can do it.

Comment: There are other common frameworks that can use the no-argument constructor, but still somehow access properties within the constructor despite absolutely no context being passed in?  I'm not sure how one would accomplish that, short of using some variant of the singleton design pattern using static constants.  Spring, and most mainstream IoC containers I'm aware of, avoid this pattern, as it has its own pitfalls.  But if you know of other modern frameworks that can accomplish this, I'd be interested to hear about them to expand my knowledge in this front.

Comment: Either way, based on your comments, you don't so much _need_ to have a constructor declared as `Program` as you _want_ to have it, and feel that it should have it based on your expectation of behavior of inversion-of-control frameworks such as Spring.

Comment: I've expanded this into its own answer, since it answers a different question ("How can I access a field-based application property within a no-argument constructor") than the one this answer assumes ("How can I create an object that uses a particular application property value").  https://stackoverflow.com/a/64531634/1108305  Note that the question as posed is completely unclear that this is the goal; "So, what am I missing ? I have tried several examples, none worked." is the question asked, which doesn't make this requirement clear.

Comment: I am not sure now who or what is unclear. I gave a simple code example and said exactly what needs to be done... Like I said, moving on. I don't really have time for this.

Comment: Upvoted your answer as a token of appreciation. I will accept if edited with a simple "cannot be done as requested"  Thanks, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong, just don't do it in a constructor...

Answer (score 1):

Other answers on this question are written assuming the goal is creating a Spring-managed bean that uses the given property in its creation.  However, based on your comments in another answer, it looks like the question you want answered is how to access an externalized property (one provided by `@Value`) within a no-argument constructor.  This is based on your expectation that a Java inversion of control (IoC) container such as Spring should allow accessing externalized properties (and presumably other dependencies) within a no-argument constructor.  That being the case, this answer will address the specific question of accessing the property within a no-argument constructor.

While there are certainly ways this goal could be achieved, none of them would be idiomatic usage of the Spring framework.  As you discovered, autowired fields (i.e. fields initialized using setter injection) cannot be accessed within the constructor.

There are two parts to explaining why this is.  First, why does it work the way it does, programmatically?  Second, why was it designed the way it was?

The [setter-based dependency injection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-setter-injection) section of the Spring docs addresses the first question:

> Setter-based DI is accomplished by the container calling setter methods on your beans after invoking a no-argument constructor or a no-argument `static` factory method to instantiate your bean.

In this case, it means that first the object is created using the no-argument constructor.  Second, once the object is constructed, the `appTitle` is initialized on the constructed bean.  Since the field isn't initialized until after the object is constructed, it will have its default value of `null` within the constructor.

The second question is why Spring is designed this way, rather than somehow having access to the property within the constructor.  The [constructor-based or setter-based DI?](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-constructor-vs-setter-injection) sidebar within the Spring documentation makes it clear that constructor arguments are in fact the idiomatic approach when dealing with mandatory dependencies in general.

> Since you can mix constructor-based and setter-based DI, it is a good rule of thumb to use constructors for mandatory dependencies and setter methods or configuration methods for optional dependencies.  [...]
>
> The Spring team generally advocates constructor injection, as it lets you implement application components as immutable objects and ensures that required dependencies are not null. Furthermore, constructor-injected components are always returned to the client (calling) code in a fully initialized state.  [...]
>
> Setter injection should primarily only be used for optional dependencies that can be assigned reasonable default values within the class.  [...]

A property needed to construct the object certainly would be categorized as a mandatory dependency.  Therefore, idiomatic Spring usage would be to pass in this required value in the constructor.

So in summary, trying to access an application property within a no-argument constructor is not supported by the Spring framework, and in fact runs contrary to the recommended use of the framework.